# How would you say it in Russian: "world's most okayest employee"

Tags: перевод, значения

I stopped for a minute trying to come up with a translation what would preserve the nuances, could not find any decent one. Need help

UPDATE:

sorry for having to explain what's implied: the words at play are the "most" implying a winner of a contest that conflicts with "okayest" implying an absolute mediocre person who cannot win anything

Comment: Самый ОКейный работник в мире, but in reality "самый подходящий".

Comment: Without the context some nuances might be evading me. Could you expand on those please and/or provide some context?

Comment: This expression is nonsensical and ungrammatical, deliberately so, for humorous effect. Can you tell us where you heard it and what was the intended meaning?

Comment: it's a text on a mug, yes it's for fun only

Comment: "Самая выдающаяся посредственность нашей Партии".

Comment: @Headcrab you nailed it, i like it even better as it comes from the history

Comment: "Самый удовлетворительный сотрудник"

Answer (score 2):

My take:

**самый нормальный** (в мире)

**самый годный** (в мире)

Obviously these don't have the double superlative. If it's indispensable for translation, then

**самый зачётнейший** (в мире)

UPDATE:

After being given the rundown, my suggestions are

**самому посредственному**

**самому неказистому**

**самому обыкновенному / среднестатистическому / ничем не примечательному /
невыдающемуся / заурядному**

Comment: the original phrase has a conflict in it: "most" calls for something at the top while "okayest" calls for something at the very middle, hence fun and laughter, you options lack it